# Authentication Issue Adding A Web Service

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight, web-services

I am currently experiencing an error deploying a silverlight application that uses web services.

I have developed the application on my laptop, which ran locally, and compiled fine. I am now at the clients location, and am using the clients PC to compile the application and deploy. I have done this previously without error.

Previously I have had to deploy the web service, then within the silverlight application, delete the service reference and re-add it, this time selecting the deployed service instead of the local service.

Today however this is not working, and asks for a username and password to add the service. However, this only appears when using a fully qualified domain name - eg liveweb.company. If I try the IP of the machine, it adds the reference just fine without need for a password.

What is the difference between adding an IP based reference and a domain reference? Why would one need authentication and not the other?

IIS is confiuged to use windows authentication, but entering valid credentials for this will still not allow you to add the service reference in Visual Studio.

Any tips very much appreciated!

EDIT: This post is identical to my problem. Has there been a recent patch which has broken something? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/tfssetup/thread/31578cce-760f-44ed-86cc-d799e0239a4d

Comment: Actually you can avoid this by dynamically refering the url from the config file itself, which avoids the building at the client site. Please refer the link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12317/How-to-make-your-Web-Reference-proxy-URL-dynamic

Comment: @AmalDev - that would be ideal, however, I am using Service References rather than web services, and they do not appear to have the option to set the URL to static or dynamic.